# How to detect symbol rename in Visual Studio 2015 extension using roslyn?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsx

Is there any way for a Visual Studio 2015 extension to detect when a symbol rename occurs in a solution, and act upon it?  Or perhaps this functionality is available in Roslyn somewhere?  I found the [`IRefactorNotifyService`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures/IRefactorNotifyService.cs,105fce9fe60cc318) in Roslyn, but this seems to be an internal class.  Is there a public supported way of doing this? (Either in Visual Studio through EnvDTE or similar, or using Roslyn)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the existing [`IVsHierarchyRefactorNotify` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchyrefactornotify), which predates Roslyn.

In fact, the point of Roslyn's `IRefactorNotifyService` is to bridge to this VS interface ([source](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices/Implementation/VsRefactorNotifyService.cs))